# finding the specific word from another word in java

Tags: java, string, dictionary

Lets say i have a two word (equal length) in my dictionary first one is `DAMP` second one is `LIKE`. I will change only one character from `DAMP` in every attempt(turn) and when i change the one character it will be,should be the existing word in the dictionary. One function will control the dictionary is the changed word in the dictionary or not `public boolean isInDictionary(String myword)` When i find the word i want to write it to console. Thanks in advance. Just need an idea not all algorithm.

**E.g.**

**Words :** DAMP, LIKE

**Steps :** DAMP **->** LAMP **->** LIMP **->** LIME **->** LIKE

Comment: What have you tried? We're not just going to write the entire program for you. Check the [FAQ].

Comment: Just need an idea. Not entire algorithm

Comment: all the chars that will be replaced are going to be randome?

Comment: thank you for your care, yes it will be the random changing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a [Hamming Distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance). For given two words of equal length, it is the number of positions at which the corresponding symbols are different.

Your algorithm could look like this:

1. Organize your words into a graph structure, where two words are connected only when Hamming distance between them equals 1, i.e. : DAMP and LAMP will be connected (h.d. is 1), but DAMP and LIMP - no (h.d. is 2).
2. For given two words, check if there exists a path in your graph between first word and  second. If so, write the path. For this you can use any of [pathfinind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pathfinding) algorithm.

Example

Words : DAMP, LIKE

We are searching our graph and finds that there is a path between those words. Using, for example, [Dijkstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra's_algorithm) we find following path:

Path : DAMP -> LAMP -> LIMP -> LIME -> LIKE

Comment: Thank you. i'm trying now..